# Why is there such a problem when using PHP block inside of HTML attribute?

Tags: php, string, syntax, attributes, quotes

I am going to ask this very simply.

Inside the example below, the () {} brackets are working as intended and are colored appropriately in my editor (atom):

```
<p> "<?php if(){} ?>" </p>
```

In the example below, the () {} brackets are not colored how they are meant to be colored, in my editor (atom):

```
<p name= "<?php if(){} ?>" ></p>
```

In the code below, the () {} are NOT colored appropriately, but the function WORKS (both for true, and false):

```
<p name=" <?php if (TRUE) { echo "it is ok" } else { echo "it is not ok" } ?> "></p>
```

So everything is good right? It's just syntax highlighting problem, right? WRONG!
If I type this....

```
<?php if (FALSE) { ?> <input value=" <?php echo "it is ok"; } ?> ">
```

... If FALSE, then the browser outputs "> where the input field is meant to be.
(If TRUE, then it displays what you'd expect, an input field with a value "it is ok".)

- But **why**? There are two, distinct php-blocks.
- This is **only** a problem inside **attributes**. NOT inside other quotes in HTML.
- **How** to work around this?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Of course `">` will be printed as it is outside your `if (FALSE)`.

Comment: As @u_mulder says, you didn't nest the PHP and HTML properly.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the comment. But it doesn't make so much sense (at least in how PHP behaves in other instances. 

I definitely know that I can open if function, inside php-blocks, and then close it in another place using php blocks.

This is the php part:
if (FALSE) { echo "it is ok"; } (result = it is ok)

This is the html part:
<input value="">

So even if it is false, logically it should just not activate the if statement, and I be left with the html part above. This is what doesn't make sense. Any input guys? @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Your last statment shud be

```
  <?php if (FALSE):?>
     <input value="it is ok">
  <?php endif;?>
```

inline

```
 <?php if (FALSE):?><input value="it is ok"><?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks man. I have indeed found this way of writing it and could have used it in this case. I just wanted to grab the fundamentals.

In the example above, the if statement shouldn't activate, and so you get <input value=""> that is left. So I don't get why it's "> that is left. I know for a fact that you can split PHP functions amongst many blocks. It doesn't make sense why people have marked me -2 "not useful or researched question," when I have done my best to research my question and digest it to the very fundamentals. How else are we meant to ask questions here then?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found it. Best way, that makes sense to me is:

```
<?php if (FALSE): ?> <input value="<?php echo $validId; ?>"> <?php endif; ?>
```

OR, in other words

```
<?php if (FALSE){ ?> <input value="<?php echo $validId; ?>"> <?php } ?>
```

I could echo the whole thing, but I just want to echo the value. If you put closing brackets outside of HTML quotes, then you are ok.

It doesn't make sense to me why people mark it down, when I have researched it so well and presented it so clearly. This usually works in most cases, but inside HTML attribute quotes, php just acts extra weird. That is my finding so far.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
<?php if (FALSE) { ?> <input value=" <?php echo "it is ok"; } ?> ">
```

the `">` at the end is not inside the `if` body. So it's printed unconditionally. So when the condition fails (as it must since it's `FALSE`) you don't print the beginning `<input` but you still print `">`, which is unmatched and produces invalid HTML.

Comment: Hey thanks man! I have just realized this today actually. Haha had a eureka moment. Thank you so much for a simple explanation.